# How can I comment out or in a section in source code with sed or awk

Tags: sed, awk

Currently, I have files which contain sections like this:

```
code statement1
code statement2
# BEGIN SOMENAME
some code
some other code
# END SOMENAME
code statement n +1
code statement n +1
```

What I want to do is to comment out what is between

```
# BEGIN SOMENAME
```

and

```
# END
```

so that in the end, it looks like this:

```
code statement1
code statement2
# BEGIN SOMENAME
# some code
# some other code
# END SOMENAME
code statement n +1
code statement n +1
```

Can I achieve this with `awk` or `sed`?   And can I reverse it easily with an operation that "comments in" again?

What I want to avoid is making mistakes, so if the lines are already commented out
they should be left alone. Also, in "comment in", it should not try to do something if the lines between the end and begin do not start with a `#`.

---

Found a possible solution:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { 
        i=0; 
        line_with_no_comment_found=0 
    }
    
    /^# END/ { 
        m=0;
        if ( line_with_no_comment_found == 1 ) { 
            for (var in a) print "# "a[var] 
        } else { 
            for (var in a) print a[var] 
        }
        delete a;
        i=0;
        line_with_no_comment_found=0;
    }
    
    /^# / { 
        if (m==0) { 
            print 
        } else { 
            a[i++]=$0; 
        }
    }
    
    !/^# / { 
        if (m==0) { 
            print 
        } else { 
            a[i++]=$0; 
            line_with_no_comment_found=1
        }
    }
    
    /^# BEGIN ([a-zA-Z_])([1-9][0-9]*)*/ {
        m=1;
    }
    END { }
'<<EOF
```

Comment: maybe, because this old code has mistakes like that multiple begin lines (copy/paste bugs...?)   after another, and you just need ignore the first one or sometime the begin starts and the file ends....  i'd rather not post this script, its competly broken now....

Comment: you are right. added this to challenges. Sorry got tired, and it seems always when i found a partial solution, all other things stop working

Answer (score 0):

This script works for me. I tested it in GNU Awk 4.0.1, but should work in Nawk as well.

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    # action=0: uncomment
    # action=1: comment
    action=0
    in_optional_code_block=0
}
{
    if ($0 ~ /^# BEGIN/) {
        in_optional_code_block=1
    } else if ($0 ~ /^# END/) {
        in_optional_code_block=0
    } else if (in_optional_code_block) {
        if (action) {
            if ($0 !~ /^#/) {
                $0 = "# " $0
            }
        } else {
            if ($0 ~ /^#/) {
                sub(/^# ?/, "")
            }
        }
    }
}
1'
```

I also wrote a small accompanying shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

syntax_error() {
    echo "Usage: `basename \"$0\"` [comment|uncomment] file" >&2
    exit 1
}

case "$1" in
    0|uncomment) action=0; ;;
    1|comment) action=1; ;;
    *) syntax_error; ;;
esac
shift
if [ -z "$@" ]; then syntax_error; fi

awk 'BEGIN {
    action='$action'
    in_optional_code_block=0
}
{
    if ($0 ~ /^# BEGIN/) {
        in_optional_code_block=1
    } else if ($0 ~ /^# END/) {
        in_optional_code_block=0
    } else if (in_optional_code_block) {
        if (action) {
            if ($0 !~ /^#/) {
                $0 = "# " $0
            }
        } else {
            if ($0 ~ /^#/) {
                sub(/^# ?/, "")
            }
        }
    }
}
1' "$@" > ".$@.commentswap"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then mv ".$@.commentswap" "$@"; fi
```

(If you have GNU Awk 4.1.0 or later, you can use the -i flag instead of the move construction at the end.)

Comment: @Mandragor If SOMENAME in the opening and closing comments have to match, give me a shout.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the "possible solution" in the question,
there are a few issues in your suggested code:

- The loop `for (var in a)` is not guaranteed to iterate over the indexes of `a` in order, which will have the consequence that the lines that you comment might be outputted in a random order.
- Your patterns for detecting the `BEGIN` and `END` lines do not attempt to pair up the label used on either line, so that `# BEGIN FOO` may be ended by `# END BAR`.
- There are unnecessary duplication of code between the `/^# /` block and the `!/^# /` block.
- An empty `END` block is needlessly present.
- The code does not un-comment.

---

To easier be able to un-comment the commented lines in the sections that are affected by the commenting, we also add extra `#` characters to the start and end marker lines:

```bash
sed '/^# BEGIN SOMENAME$/,/^# END SOMENAME$/ s/^/#/' file
```

This inserts a single `#` character at the start of each line between the `# BEGIN SOMENAME` and `# END SOMENAME` lines, including on those marker lines.

This would, for the given text, result in

```
code statement1
code statement2
## BEGIN SOMENAME
#some code
#some other code
## END SOMENAME
code statement n +1
code statement n +1
```

If `#` were only inserted on lines where that character was not already the first character, it would be unreasonably difficult to reverse the operation as there is no log of what lines were originally commended out between the marker lines.

To un-comment this:

```bash
sed '/^## BEGIN SOMENAME$/,/^## END SOMENAME$/ s/#//' file
```

This affects only the lines commended using the first `sed` command, returning them to their original state by removing the inserted `#` character at the start of each line.

Would you want to comment out the lines using `#` followed by a space character, then use

```bash
sed '/^# BEGIN SOMENAME$/,/^# END SOMENAME$/ s/^/# /' file
```

for commenting, and

```bash
sed '/^# # BEGIN SOMENAME$/,/^# # END SOMENAME$/ s/# //' file
```

for un-commenting.

---

The equivalent operations using `awk` instead of `sed`:

For commenting:

```bash
awk '$0 == "# BEGIN SOMENAME", $0 == "# END SOMENAME" { $0 = "#" $0 }; 1' file
```

For un-commenting:

```bash
awk '$0 == "## BEGIN SOMENAME", $0 == "## END SOMENAME" { $0 = substr($0, 2) }; 1' file
```

In both these commands, I use string comparisons instead of regular expressions since these are generally faster, and there's no need to involve any pattern matching.  The `substr()` call in the second command (for un-commenting) would return the input string minus the first character. The lone trailing `1` causes the current line to be output.